# Insert section symbol in R markdown document

Tags: r, latex, markdown, symbols

How can I insert a section symbol in an R markdown document?

Since I don't know how to insert the symbol into this question, I will refer you to this page instead, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_sign.

I am able to incorporate other symbols using Latex, for example `$\dag$` gives me a dagger and `$\ddag$` gives me a double dagger.  (Both the dagger and the double dagger can be viewed at the page link above.)  But if I use `$\s$` or `$\S$` (which I found on an internet search) for the section symbol, I simply get $\s$ in $\S$ in my document.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The section symbol isn't a math symbol, so it doesn't need to be in math mode (inside dollar signs). If you just use `\S`, you will get it.

Minimal example:

```
---
title: "Section Symbol"
author: "Gregor"
date: "November 16, 2015"
output: pdf_document
---

\S this is the section symbol.
```

[image]

If you need to use it inside math mode, you can enclose it in `\text{}`, for example this will produce a display equation, Gamma = Section Symbol (feel free to use `$$` instead of `\[`):

```
\[
    \Gamma = \text{\S}
\]
```

Of course, special code in markdown depends on your destination format. The above will work if you're compiling to PDF via LaTeX. If you destination format is HTML, then according to the Wikipedia link in the question, the code is `&sect;`, and this works for me:

```
---
title: "Section Symbol"
author: "Gregor"
date: "November 16, 2015"
output: html_document
---

&sect; this is the section symbol.
```

Notice that the output is now `html_document`. **This worked for Word as well.**

Though less easy to remember / more manual, you can also insert the Unicode section symbol character straight into your Rmd document. You can probably copy/paste the symbol out of your Wikipedia link, or follow the "Typing Character" instructions from the Wikipedia link, such as Alt+0167 on Windows.

Comment: I just tried it.  When I use `\S`, it doesn't insert anything into my document.

Comment: Did you try my minimal example? Are you using LaTeX and compiling to PDF?  If you're compiling to HTML, your Wikipedia link says that `&sect;` will work.

Comment: I'm compiling to Word with knitr.

Comment: I just tried using `$\text{\S}$` and that inserted $\text{\S}$.

Comment: Also possible to use the html entity `&#167;` html entity tables will get you nearly every special character you want.

Comment: Thanks!  That worked.  I used `&sect;` and the section symbol was inserted.

Comment: You're right, @jeremycg, I used `&#167;` and that inserted the section symbol as well.

Comment: Note: pasting the unicode character into the markdown text via utf8 encoding will typically not produce the desired result when compiling a PDF (tested with lualatex and xelatex).

Answer (score 0):

Extending @GregorThomas's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33746228/1349673) to one that works for both pdf and html output:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
S_symbol <- 
  if (knitr::is_html_output()) {
    "&sect;"
  } else {
    "\\S"
  }
```
````

```markdown
`r S_symbol` this is the section symbol.
```